# Program output in wrong order

Tags: c, eclipse, console, eclipse-cdt

I working on a C project in Eclipse environment the code is correct and executable but the output
lines are not in order the program ask user to
 enter a number from 1-5    then asks for a name then street
but nothing appear on console screen unless i entered these values

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char name[20], address[30];

    char c;
    printf("How do you feel on a scale of 1-5?");
    c = getchar();

       printf("Enter name: ");
       scanf("%s", &name);

       printf("Enter your address: ");
       scanf("%s", &address);

       printf("Entered Name: %s\n", name);
       printf("Entered address:%s\n", address);

       printf("You said you feel: ");
       putchar(c);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It may come as a surprise, but the problem is not with Eclipse. If the program doesn't work the code is wrong.

Comment: Can you describe how things are out of order?

Comment: the right order is how do you feel on scale 1-5?1,Enter name :ryanyuyu ,Enter your adress : Egypt  but the output with me is           1
ryanyuyu 
Egypt
How do you feel on a scale of 1-5?Enter name: Enter your address: Entered Name: ryanyuyu
Entered address:Egypt
You said you feel: 1

Comment: the console screen do not ask to enter values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that stdout is line buffered (when going to a console), so unless you print a newline character, the output will remain buffered and not be displayed (OK, there's going to be a maximum size that can be buffered put that's just detail, your small amount of output will remain in buffer).

The two solutions that occur to me are, use `fflush (stdout);` after your first 3 `printf` calls, this will cause the stdout buffer to be flushed to the console, and should resolve your problems.

You could also turn off buffering of stdout, see `setvbuf` for how to do this, but I think, placing this call near the start of main (before any output) should work (untested):

```
setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Comment: at the beginning of program i used setvbuf and works also

Comment: use this scanf(" %s", &name); leading space character in scanf.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your second scanf is capturing the \n character of the previous input, try to use fgets in order to avoid this behaviour.